# ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad not detecting physical buttons

Tags: touchpad, button, elantech

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed in an Acer A315-51-54AP with ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad and with the synaptics driver. As the title says, the physical click buttons are not working while tapping does (thanks to the synaptics driver). Here is my `xinput`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 2.4G Mouse                                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ VGA WebCam: VGA WebCam                    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys
```

as well as `xinput list-props 13`

```
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
        Device Enabled (172):   0
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (174): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        Device Accel Profile (305):     1
        Device Accel Constant Deceleration (306):       2.500000
        Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (307):       1.000000
        Device Accel Velocity Scaling (308):    12.500000
        Synaptics Edges (329):  129, 3105, 126, 2216
        Synaptics Finger (330): 1, 1, 0
        Synaptics Tap Time (331):       160
        Synaptics Tap Move (332):       175
        Synaptics Tap Durations (333):  180, 180, 100
        Synaptics ClickPad (334):       1
        Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (335):  0
        Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (336):    282
        Synaptics Two-Finger Width (337):       7
        Synaptics Scrolling Distance (338):     78, 78
        Synaptics Edge Scrolling (339): 0, 0, 0
        Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (340):   1, 0
        Synaptics Move Speed (341):     0.000000, 7.392388, 0.050100, 0.000000
        Synaptics Off (342):    1
        Synaptics Locked Drags (343):   0
        Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (344):   5000
        Synaptics Tap Action (345):     0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3
        Synaptics Click Action (346):   1, 3, 0
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling (347):     0
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (348):    0.100007
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (349):     0
        Synaptics Circular Pad (350):   0
        Synaptics Palm Detection (351): 0
        Synaptics Palm Dimensions (352):        10, 200
        Synaptics Coasting Speed (353): 20.000000, 50.000000
        Synaptics Pressure Motion (354):        30, 160
        Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (355): 1.000000, 1.000000
        Synaptics Resolution Detect (356):      1
        Synaptics Grab Event Device (357):      0
        Synaptics Gestures (358):       1
        Synaptics Capabilities (359):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
        Synaptics Pad Resolution (360): 31, 31
        Synaptics Area (361):   0, 0, 0, 0
        Synaptics Soft Button Areas (362):      1617, 0, 1920, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        Synaptics Noise Cancellation (363):     19, 19
        Device Product ID (298):        2, 14
        Device Node (297):      "/dev/input/event8"
```

From the capabilities section it says that it does have a physical left button and no physical right button. However, none of them work. I have read some post such as [Right button on touchpad not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391879/right-button-on-touchpad-not-recognized) but the solutions there do not work. I have read also adding some kernel parameter in the grub involving i8042 [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/8fkmoz/sometimes_the_keyboard_and_touchpad_work_and/), but I do not understand which one could I use. Finally, I have tried adding the kernel parameter `psmouse.elantech_smbus=0` but no change. Also, here is my `70-synaptics.conf` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

```
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "ClickPad" "true"
        Option "TapButton1" "1"
        Option "TapButton2" "3"
        Option "TapButton3" "2"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

# This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on clickpads
# and the right and middle top areas to be right / middle buttons on clickpads
# with a top button area.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "ClickPad" "true"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
        Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "58% 0 0 15% 42% 58% 0 15%"
EndSection

# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
        MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

and `uname -a`

```
Linux tir-tan 5.4.0-31-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 20:20:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!